# Can i use django reversion only for Admin or front end as well

Tags: django, django-models, audit, django-reversion

I am trying to use Django reversion so that i can have the audit log of all changes done to all models in front end application done in `Angular JS` as front end and `Django REST` as backend.

I am thinking of using Django Reversion and their docs say this

https://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how-it-works.html

> Any models that use subclasses of VersionAdmin in the admin interface
>   will be automatically registered with django-reversion. As such, it is
>   only necessary to manually register these models if you wish to
>   override the default registration settings.

Now does that mean that i can only use that in admin site only and not on models being saved via frond end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use it in the frontend as well, study its [API](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#version-meta-data) on how to create versions yourself and handle restoring of previous/deleted versions manually as you will have to integrate it with your UI yourself...

Comment: Thanks for that i now used django simple history instead of reversion